# Installed Xcode 4.5, MPMoviePlayerController doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

I was very delighted to see that when "upgrading" to Xcode 4.5, now none of the videos in my app play at all.

Generally I do something like this:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self getBundleClip:@"theVideo"]];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.container.frame;
self.moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[self.container addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

- (NSURL*)getBundleClip:(NSString*)clip
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:clip ofType:@"mp4"];
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
}
```

Again, everything played perfectly before I updated Xcode to 4.5. Anyone else have this issue?

I also get this output:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it is not playing specifically, but it looks like behavior is different depending on which version of iOS SDK you build against. Look at the [`MPMoviePlayerController` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In particular, you may want to try calling the `prepareToPlay` method on the movie player.

Comment: This works. Where is the best place to put prepareToPlay if shouldAutoPlay is set to YES? In other words, how can you know that you are calling prepareToPlay before it actually starts playing, if you don't explicitly call "play"?

Comment: @soleil I'm not sure. The documentation doesn't specify such details about the `shouldAutoPlay` behavior. Try experimenting with exchanging the order of calling the two methods to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you define it within function?

if you use ARC, you have to retain MPMoviePlayerController

Add it to interface file!

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```